# Read logs real time with bash

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, programming, logs

I have this in the system logs:

```
Feb 27 02:53:51 Latitude-E6430 rsyslogd: action up   7
Feb 27 02:53:51 Latitude-E6430 rsyslogd: action down B
Feb 27 02:53:51 Latitude-E6430 rsyslogd: action up   U
....etc
```

I want to make a script that is monitoring the logs full time as a service, but I don't know how to do the condition.

1 - That when you read, line by line, store it in a variable.

2 - **read variable** if it finds in the line, the words [rsyslogd] and [7] it shows [echo "Found" ]

It would be a loop to read the file line by line, looking for that pattern of words.

**Example Script**

```
path_full_log="/home/full.log"


function reader_time_real(){

    while read full_log; do
        chek7=$(cat $full_log | grep "rsyslogdd" | grep 7 )
            if [[ $? = 0 ]]; then 
                echo "Found 7";

            fi

        chekB=$(cat $full_log | grep "rsyslogdd" | grep B )
            if [[ $? = 0 ]]; then 
                echo "Found B";

            fi
    done < $path_full_log
}
```

Comment: Show the script you have made so that someone can see what the errors might be.

Comment: done... more down

Comment: Please add your script to your question, not as an answer ... it will probably get   closed.

Comment: Isn't this a function of rsyslog naturally? I've only configured a syslog-ng server, but I'm thinking they are similar enough that both of them can do filters???

Comment: they are not the same, I specify in both that it has to have the word "rsyslogdd" and the 2 possible variants, 7 or B

Comment: Fixed, just change `cat $full_log` for `echo $full_log`

Comment: @BurstBass BurstBass if you fixed it, put an answer by yourself with the final version of the script, then accept your own answer.

Comment: @BurstBassBurstBass If your response was to me (you didn't tag anyone), then I think you misunderstood what I was saying.... I was saying that "I think" that syslog already has the built-in capability to do what your script is doing. I've configured a syslog-ng server before and I set up filters to catch words and send them to a separate log (even trigger commands). I would think rsyslog has the same functionality.

Answer (score 4):

Your script is not suitable to do what you want to do. It reads the file only once, but completely. If you loop this, you won't get only new output and it would be a performance nightmare.

Also, you have a useless use of `cat`, you `grep` a fixed string with a regex pattern and save the result in a variable you don't use anymore. Also you should not use unquoted filename variables.

---

Use `tail -f | grep --line-buffered`:

```bsh
tail -fn0 "$path_full_log" \
| grep -F --line-buffered 'rsyslogdd' \
| grep -Eo --line-buffered '(7|B)' \
| while read line; do
      echo "Found $line"
  done
```

Or using `xargs`:

```bsh
tail -fn0 "$path_full_log" \
| grep -F --line-buffered 'rsyslogdd' \
| grep -Eo --line-buffered '(7|B)' \
| xargs -I{} echo "Found {}"
```

- `tail -fn0` reads new lines of the file when they are added.
- `grep -F` searches for a fixed string in that line.
- `--line-buffered` tells `grep` to read lines when they come in instead of wait for the end  of the input stream which is default.
- `grep -Eo` searches for the `ERE`  pattern (`-E`) `(7|B)` and outputs only the matched string (`-o`).
- `while read line` or `xargs -I{}` takes that output and runs your command on the output (here: `echo`).

Answer (score 2):

I've made the following script, which updates every second, and highlights any new log entries. It also defines the area in which the log should be displayed (with the `logrows` and `logcols` variables), so it's made for use in a fixed size terminal window (I'm using it inside tmux).

You could probably modify this script to highlight only lines that fit a specific criteria, as you indicate.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Initial configuration variables
logrows=31
logcols=127

# Local function definition
printnew() {
  clear
  echo -e "\e[0;30;47m"
  hightail=$(tail -n "$logrows" /var/log/syslog | cut -b "1-$logcols")
  echo -ne "${hightail}\e[0m"
}

printdif() {
  (( newrows = logrows - logdiff ))
  clear
  normtail=$(tail -n "$logrows" /var/log/syslog | head -n "$newrows" | cut -b "1-$logcols")
  echo -n "$normtail"
  echo -e "\e[0;30;47m"
  hightail=$(tail -n "$logdiff" /var/log/syslog | cut -b "1-$logcols")
  echo -ne "${hightail}\e[0m"
}

printold() {
  clear
  normtail=$(tail -n "$logrows" /var/log/syslog | cut -b "1-$logcols")
  echo -n "$normtail"
}

# Loop every second
while true
do
  sleep 1 &

  # Read log sizes
  logsize=$(wc -l /var/log/syslog | cut -d ' ' -f1)
  (( logdiff = logsize - presize ))

  # If more than $logrows lines are new
  if (( logdiff > "$logrows" ))
  then
    printnew
    redraw=1
  # If less than $logrows lines but more than 0 lines are new
  elif (( logdiff > 0 ))
  then
    printdif
    redraw=1
  # If no lines are new
  else
    if [[ "$redraw" -eq 1 ]]
    then
      printold
      redraw=0
    fi
  fi

  presize="$logsize"
  wait # for sleep
done
```

The script is made with 3 scenarios in mind:

1. The entire contents of `logrows` is new - everything is highlighted (`printnew`).
2. Some lines of the log is new - these are highlighted (`printdif`).
3. No new log lines - nothing is highlighted (`printold`).

*Disclaimer: The code could probably be optimized, but I'm generally more concerned with my code being readable rather than as condensed as possible.*